# Spring Saml FilterChainProxy clearing context - null Authentication

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have a problem with Spring Security configuration relevant to Spring Saml2, which causes the **Authentication to be always null** even when the IDP responds successfully.

I am using the `spring-security-saml2-core` library `1.0.2.RELEASE` in conjunction with `spring` `4.3.0.RELEASE` and `spring-security` `4.1.0.RELEASE`.

I have a simple SP which authenticates through SSO via SSOCircle. The authentication works and debugging I can see the `SAMLAuthenticationProvider` returning an authenticated User with the granted authorities I expected. So far so good.

Although when the authentication completes I stepped into a `org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy:180` calling the following line

```
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
```

which I suspect it is the reason I have a null Authentication afterwards.

Following is the Spring Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

...

@Bean
    public SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider() {
        SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider = new SAMLAuthenticationProvider();
        samlAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetails(samlUserMappingService);
        samlAuthenticationProvider.setForcePrincipalAsString(false);
        return samlAuthenticationProvider;
    }

 @Bean
    public FilterChainProxy samlFilter() throws Exception {
        List<SecurityFilterChain> chains = new ArrayList<SecurityFilterChain>();

        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/login/**"), samlEntryPoint()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/logout/**"), samlLogoutFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/metadata/**"),
                metadataDisplayFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSO/**"),
                samlWebSSOProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSOHoK/**"),
                samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SingleLogout/**"),
                samlLogoutProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/discovery/**"), samlIDPDiscovery()));
        return new FilterChainProxy(chains);
    }



@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint());
    http.csrf().disable();
    //http.addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
    http.addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().antMatchers("/error").permitAll().antMatchers("/saml/**")
            .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
}


@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider()).eraseCredentials(false);

...
    }
```

And here is the Web initialiser:

```
public class WebInitialiser extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebMvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.addFilter("samlFilter", new DelegatingFilterProxy("samlFilter"))
                .addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), false, "/*");

        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

}
```

P.S. for extra info: I have mainly referred to the code from the following repository on github: https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample/tree/master/src/main/java/com/vdenotaris/spring/boot/security/saml/web  but I am not using Spring boot.

The application is deployed on apache-tomcat-8.0.30, and I also tried apache-tomcat-7.0.37.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer. When initialising the context, Filters were not registered properly so the wierd behaviour described above.

The solution was to create a class as follows

```
public class SecurityInitialiser extends SecurityWebApplicationInitializer(){}
```

and remove the `onStartup` method from the `WebInitialiser` class.

The reason this works in Spring boot it's because Filters are scanned and registered automatically.