# (Spring SAML) - Authentication null (following a successfull login on the IDP)

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-saml

I am trying to integrate the SAML authentication process into a JSF based application. Basically I am following this great sample project (https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample).

#### web.xml

To accomodate Spring SAML into JSF I have done some changes to `web.xml` file in the following way:

```
<listener>
     <listener-class>org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener</listener-class>
</listener>

[ ... ]

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

[ ... ]

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Enable Spring Filter: Spring Security works on the concept of Filters -->
<!-- Declare the Spring filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<!-- Defines urls pattern on which the filter is applied -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>

    <!-- mandatory to allow the managed bean to forward the request to the filter-->
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

#### The Problem

I can successfully log into my IDP because I also see that a user is created with the role `ROLE_USER` among the logs like the following:

```
SecurityContext 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@45988295: Authentication: org.springframework.security.providers.ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken@45988295: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@475365ab: Username: id_7d4e53c6262ae1c8b824dbc1c1e573d2e9e8d159; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@475365ab: Username: id_7d4e53c6262ae1c8b824dbc1c1e573d2e9e8d159; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER' stored to HttpSession: 'org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@6db3bdf2
```

But when the moment to redirect to the landing page arrives, I see in the logs something similiar:

```
SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

and I also noticed this row in the logs (maybe it's a hint of something wrong that I have done with Spring Security?)

```
Requested session IDRequested session ID ED1A0CF82BDFF1EB103ECC9DCF82BED3 is invalid
```

and finally when I am going to be redirected to the success page, I can clearly see that the `SecurityContextHolder` is **beign cleared** so basically when it arrives at the destination page, there is no more an authenticated user stored in the `SecurityContext` and that's because I arrive at the destination page with a `HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden`.
Following is a brief summary of the logs that show the situation:

```
[ ... Processing the endpoint "/saml/login" ... ]
    2020-08-26 09:42:29,625 [http-nio-8091-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /saml/login?idp=https%3A//idptest.spid.gov.it at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
    2020-08-26 09:42:29,626 [http-nio-8091-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
    2020-08-26 09:42:29,626 [http-nio-8091-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@534fe335. A new one will be created.
[ ... ]
    2020-08-26 09:42:29,770 [http-nio-8091-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
[ ... Processing the endpoint "/saml/SSO" ... ]
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,124 [http-nio-8091-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,124 [http-nio-8091-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /saml/SSO at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
    [ ... ]
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,124 [http-nio-8091-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /saml/SSO at position 1 of 1 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SAMLProcessingFilter'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,124 [http-nio-8091-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter - Request is to process authentication
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,223 [http-nio-8091-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using it.ifin.rasdm.web.config.CustomSAMLAuthenticationProvider
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,475 [http-nio-8091-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter - Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.providers.ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken@25c6bb32: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@e71c8265: Username: id_e0bbf9e5b7abe0f472324cdb06e7ffb6dd52233f; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@e71c8265: Username: id_e0bbf9e5b7abe0f472324cdb06e7ffb6dd52233f; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,475 [http-nio-8091-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler - Using default Url: /dashboard.xhtml
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,475 [http-nio-8091-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to '/DM-WEB/dashboard.xhtml'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,475 [http-nio-8091-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@6c11f040
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,475 [http-nio-8091-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession being created as SecurityContext is non-default
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,475 [http-nio-8091-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@25c6bb32: Authentication: org.springframework.security.providers.ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken@25c6bb32: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@e71c8265: Username: id_e0bbf9e5b7abe0f472324cdb06e7ffb6dd52233f; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@e71c8265: Username: id_e0bbf9e5b7abe0f472324cdb06e7ffb6dd52233f; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER' stored to HttpSession: 'org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@78325633
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,475 [http-nio-8091-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,480 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /dashboard.xhtml at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MetadataGeneratorFilter'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,480 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /dashboard.xhtml at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,480 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /dashboard.xhtml at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,480 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,480 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,480 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /dashboard.xhtml at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,480 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /dashboard.xhtml at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterChainProxy'
    [ ... Here I am being redirected to the "dashboard.xhtml" page after successful login ...]
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,480 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /dashboard.xhtml has no matching filters
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,480 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /dashboard.xhtml at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,480 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache - saved request doesn't match
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,480 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /dashboard.xhtml at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,480 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /dashboard.xhtml at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,480 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@4b018743: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,480 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /dashboard.xhtml at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,480 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter - Requested session ID 71C954116A9C4A6B942532E25469295B is invalid.
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,481 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /dashboard.xhtml at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,481 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /dashboard.xhtml at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,481 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/dashboard.xhtml'; against '/javax.faces.resource/**'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,481 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/dashboard.xhtml'; against '/'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,481 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/dashboard.xhtml'; against '/saml/**'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,481 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/dashboard.xhtml'; against '/css/**'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,481 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/dashboard.xhtml'; against '/img/**'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,481 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/dashboard.xhtml'; against '/js/**'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,481 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/dashboard.xhtml'; against '/login.xhtml'
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,481 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /dashboard.xhtml; Attributes: [authenticated]
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,481 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@4b018743: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,481 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@32cb62eb, returned: -1
    2020-08-26 09:42:36,481 [http-nio-8091-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
    org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
        at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.10.RELEASE.jar:1.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.24]
        at it.ifin.common.utils.web.servlet.ResponseHeaderFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeaderFilter.java:70) [utils-0.6.9.1.jar:0.6.9.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126) [catalina.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71) [log4j-web-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [catalina.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [catalina.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [catalina.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678) [catalina.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [catalina.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.24]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.24]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.24]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

My current issue seems something similiar with this one ([Spring Saml FilterChainProxy clearing context - null Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39513688/spring-saml-filterchainproxy-clearing-context-null-authentication)), but I have already tried out its solution without success.

Any hint (also I am not using Spring Boot)?

Comment: I don't see anything jsf related in here

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje, Maybe it's not relevant but I inserted JSF tag for clarity and because that's what I am using as the base of the application (with Primefaces). To be more specific I am using the Mojarra JSF's implementation (version 2.3.9 from `org.glassfish`) ..

Comment: Tags are for what is a proven or strongly suspected part of the problem. In this case I doubt it is. While you think it might make things clear, it also makes people following the tag reading it and spending time on it. At the same time, it might deter others that follow spring security and know nothing about JSF to not read the question while it might be something they know. And adding a specific impl like mojarra as a tag implies it is ONLY a Mojarra problem and not a MyFacces one.

Comment: Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging (third time I post this link in a question this morning) on how to (not) use tags in titles.  And you don't use spring for other things? (Since I see you also use CDI) Then I'd strongly suggest to use a different authentication framework and not use Spring Security. Not that it is bad (I have no clue, don't use spring myself) but to prevent possible clashes and mixed/weird behaviour of which you already might encounter one now.

Comment: http://picketlink.org/ is an alternative if you don't use spring for other things

Comment: Ok @Kukeltje, I will remove those extra JSF tags as they can create confusion. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yes, I am using both CDI and Spring (for the declaration of beans like `HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean` & co. inside an `applicationContext.xml` file for the login process that allows me to login from the frontend using username and passsword).
Note that I will likely have two login strategies: the traditional form based and a SAML authentication.

Comment: But you are ONLY using spring for the login part, not injection and other things. Then I strongly suggest to not use spring security. Just my €0.02

Comment: Will you please post all the debug logs, beginning from the request that processes the SAML response and ending where access is denied?

Comment: Hi @jzheaux, I tried to improve the logs by including more information .. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was correctly working while using Spring Boot and embedded Tomcat, but when I wanted to remove Spring Boot and use the external Tomcat it was giving me this headache because of a cookie setting in the external Tomcat's `context.xml` file.

**Wrong Setting**
Originally I had this setting for the `sameSite` cookies configuration in the previously mentioned file:

```
<CookieProcessor sameSiteCookies="Strict"/>
```

This way I was able to login through Spring SAML but at the moment of reaching the `relayState` in the Web Application it couldn't find the `Authentication` object in the `SecurityContextHolder`.

**Correct Setting**
I changed the `sameSiteCookies` by setting it the following way:

```
<CookieProcessor sameSiteCookies="Lax"/>
```

Now I can correctly do login and logout with Spring SAML without Spring Boot.